# How do i blur modal background upon clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to blur modal background upon clicking a button that has a class called 'update2'. Currently this is what i am doing.I am not sure why its not working though.

**Jquery code for blurring body**

```
$(".update2").on("click", function() {

    // State changes
    $("body").addClass("blur-filter");    
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body onload="my_entrys()">
  <div id = "entryOne" class = "entries"> 
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><button id = "entryButton1" onclick="view_entry(${entry.id})" class = "update2">View</button></td>
        <td><button id = "entryButton2" onclick="edit_entry(${entry.id})"class="update2" >Edit</button></td>
        <td><button id = "entryButton3" onclick="delete_entry(${entry.id})"class="delete" >Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </div>                   
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.blur-filter {
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    -moz-filter: blur(2px);
    -o-filter: blur(2px);
    -ms-filter: blur(2px);
    filter: blur(2px);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the code necessary to run it. `my_entrys()` is not shown. If that function is not relevant, please remove it.

Comment: you should add a ```div``` in background and then use the ```blur-filter``` class to it instead adding the class to whole body, which itself contains the modal.

Comment: What is this `${entry.id}`

Comment: Also, `filter` is a well-supported standard at this point. There is no need for the vendor prefixes.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, comment about filter is noted.

Comment: @SachinBhandari, great idea.